# What is the proper way to set default method parameter in PHP?

Tags: php

Let's say you have a method that expects a numerical value as an argument. What's the proper way to set a default value in the event the argument doesn't exist?

```
public function saveme($myvar = false) {}

public function saveme($myvar = '') {}

public function saveme($myvar = NULL) {}

public function saveme($myvar = 0) {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of those are valid, and neither one is "more correct" for all cases. It depends entirely on what the valid range of values are for the function and what the function is supposed to do. Typically, the default type will match the expected input type, unless you want a place-holder for "no value" in which case `null` is typically used.

If your function can perform something useful with default of `0`, use `0`. If your function needs to tell the difference between having been explicitly given a single argument of `0` and having been given no arguments, or if `0` is not a sane default, use `null`.

Comment: The questions is about numerical value.

Comment: Let's say it should only be a numerical value. Nothing else that would be associated with letters. And vice versa, but for alpha characters, I would probably stick with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

```
function myFunc ($myType = 0) {}
```

Comment: Ya that is the proper way to set a numeric type default value, I didn't mean for it to come across as snarky.